# C#: How to construct a derived class from an existing base class object?

Tags: c#, derived, construct

Consider this, please:

```
class MyTreeNode: TreeNode{
   int x;
   public MyTreeNode(TreeNode tn)
   {
      x=1; 
      // Now what to do here with 'tn'???
   }
```

I know how to use `x`. But how should I use `tn` here to assign it to my `MyTreeNode` object?

Comment: In your code there is no TreeNode object in MyTreeNode. You just set the class MyTreeNode to inherit of TreeNode and provide it's public methods/Props and use private methods. This you can access with base.x. If you want to store a TreeNode object in MyTreeNode u need to instaciated one

Comment: I guess you have an instance of `TreeNode`, and you want to build a `MyTreeNode` that is derived from `TreeNode`, with all same values in it, and an extra property `x`, am I correct?

Comment: You are exactly right Danny Chen. Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to assign the `tn` to your `MyTreeNode`? It allready inherits from it. If you´re planning to create a copy of `tn` but of type `MyTreeNode` you should create a copy-constructor:

```
int x;
public MyTreeNode(TreeNode tn)
{
    // copy tn´s attributes first
    this.myProp = tn.myProp;
    // ... all the other properties from tn

    // now set the value for x
    this.x = 1; 
}
```

However if you also have private members on your base-class which have to be copied this is much more difficult, you´d have to use reflection in this case to have access to those private members (e.g. fields).

Comment: OMG! Do you mean I should repeat it for all base class properties?

Comment: Yeap, you have to create a completely new instance.

Answer (score 2):

As other comments stated you need a copy constructor.
I would use the following code, so that I can also copy private properties without reflection.

```
class TreeNode
{
    private int myProp; //value type field
    private TreeNode parentNode; //reference type field
    public TreeNode(TreeNode tn) //copy constructor
    {
        //copy all the properties/fields that are value types
        this.myProp = tn.myProp;
        //if you have reference types fields properties you need to create a copy of that instance to it as well
        this.parentNode = new TreeNode(parentNode);
    }
    //You can have other constructors here
}

class MyTreeNode: TreeNode{
   int x;
   public MyTreeNode(TreeNode tn):base(tn) //This calls the copy constructor before assigning x = 1
   {
      x=1; 
   }
```

Comment: Oh, the idea of the copy-ctor within the base-class to avoid reflection is really nice. +1 for this

Comment: But TreeNode is a .NET base class and I cannot modify it to add a copy constructor for it. Can I?

Comment: In this case you need to create the constructor in the derived class, as @HimBromBeere showed you. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631898/c-sharp-inheritance-derived-class-from-base-class[/link] It is shown how you cand do it with reflection.