# Generic methods and accessing concrete instance properties

Tags: c#, generics, abstract

I have these classes (just an example):

```
/* Data classes */

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public InfoData<TInfo> : Data
    where TInfo: InfoBase
{
    public TInfo Info { get; set; }
    ...
}

/* Info classes */

// ABSTRACT
public abstract class InfoBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ExtraInfo : InfoBase
{
    public IList<InfoBase> Related { get; set; }
}

// + other InfoBase inherited types
```

Then I have a method that consumes `Data` (or any inherited type instance) but has to read additional properties of actual object instance being passed as parameter:

```
TData Add<TData>(TData data)
    where TData: Data
{
    TData result = Get(
        data.Id,
        ...
        // how do I get to this one?
        data.Related[0].Id
    );
}
```

I can get to all `Data` class properties, but how do I get to additional properties of the actual instance because I can't just cast to something like

```
data as InfoData<InfoBase>
```

because `InfoBase` is abstract and I also can't change abstract generic with some inherited non-abstract type because there would be too many to consider...

### Questions

1. How can I get to `Related` property if few inherited classes have it?
2. Is there a better way to implement my method?

Comment: I think this post answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729527/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-base-class-object-to-a-derived-class-reference-with-a

Comment: @PrzemG not exactly the answer as they're casting incompatible types. In my case I would like to access **actual** instance properties not something like accessing `Length` of type `object`... but I can see why the same applies in my case as it doesn't really matter whether types are compatible or not. It just won't work.

Comment: @PrzemG: ...but I can see why the same applies in my case as it doesn't really matter whether types are compatible or not. Casting to derived types just won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem in casting to abstract, you can also add Interface definition and have your classes inherit them for example:

```
public interface IRelated{
    IList<InfoBase>Related {get; set;}
}

public class ExtraInfo : InfoBase, IRelated
{
    public IList<InfoBase> Related { get; set; }
}

public class OtherInfo:IRelated{
    public IList<InfoBase> Related { get; set; }
}
```

and cast to interface instead class:

```
ExtraInfo i = new ExtraInfo(){ Id = 5 };
var p = (InfoBase)i;
var q = (IRelated)i;
q.Related.Add(new ExtraInfo());
```

However I can see other problem in your code: in the Add method you mistype properties:

```
data.Related.Id
```

since data.Related returns IList of InfoBase not the InfoBase class itself.

### Edit:

You have to be more clear what do you expect to get from the related (or what is Get parameter list).

### Edit 2:

here is the Add method code for you:

```
TData Add<TData>(TData data) where TData:Data
{
    var infoBase = data as InfoBase; //or IRelated as in my earlier samples
    TData result;
    if (infoBase != null)
    {
        result = Get(data.id, infoBase.Related[0].Id); //you can also use infoBase.Id as first param
    }
    else
    {
        result = Get(data.id, null); //whatever you need to pass to the method if there is no related item
    }
}
```

### Edit 3:

here's working code:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class InfoData<TInfo> : Data
    where TInfo: InfoBase
{
    public TInfo Info { get; set; }
    //...
}

/* Info classes */

// ABSTRACT
public abstract class InfoBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //  ...
}

public interface IRelated
{
    IList<InfoBase> Related {get; set;}
}

public class ExtraInfo : InfoBase, IRelated
{
    public IList<InfoBase> Related { get; set; }
}

public class OtherInfo : InfoBase, IRelated
{
    public IList<InfoBase> Related { get; set; }
}

...

class MainClass
{
    public static TData Get<TData>(int id, int? related)
        where TData: Data
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id: {0}, related:{1}", id, related);
        return (TData)null;
    }

    public static TData Add<TData>(TData data)
        where TData: Data
    {
        return Get<TData>(data.Id,null);
    }

    public static TData Add<TData, TInfo>(TData data)
        where TData: InfoData<TInfo>
        where TInfo: InfoBase
    {
        var infoBase = data.Info as IRelated;

        if (infoBase == null)
            return Get<TData>(data.Id, null);

        return Get<TData>(data.Id, infoBase.Related[0].Id);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var i = new ExtraInfo {
            Id = 5,
            Related = new List<InfoBase> { new ExtraInfo { Id = 1 }}
        };

        var data = new InfoData<ExtraInfo> { Id = 100, Info = i };
        var result1 = Add<InfoData<ExtraInfo>, ExtraInfo>(data);
        var result2 = Add(data);
    }
}
```

but... this whole code does not look good :)

There are couple possible improvements:

- you can move Add method into the class Data and then override
- you can pass related Id into the add method instead of passing the whole object
- you can re-think the domain and check if you really need so much overloads.

Comment: That was just a typo yes... Corrected. but apart from what you've written can you provide an example by re-writing my `Add` method to incorporate your supposed solution?

Comment: This isn't correct. You're casting `TData` which may be either `Data` or `InfoData<InfoBase>` to `InfoBase` directly. This is already a compile time error... It's not as simple as you might've though. If it was this simple I wouldn't be asking a question here.

Comment: yes, you are right, it was my mistake. Please see my latest edit

Comment: Well your code is close. You've introduced `IRelated` interface but you haven't used it in methods. Actually if you would use it in second `Add<TData, TInfo>` it would simply cover all `InfoBase` inherited classes that also implement this specific interface. But I figured this has to be done as per type anyway. I'm currently doing something similar to your first alinee suggestion but instead of putting it directly on `Data` as I'm not using *active record* pattern I've rather written extension methods that get my first related `Id`.

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aq325B) that uses `IRelated` generic type constraint hence `Add` method can be used with `ExtraInfo` as well as `OtherInfo` object instances why also eliminating few lines of code that try to read `infoBase`.

Comment: brilliant tool, never heard about it :) I have created fork with using Reflection - simplifies things a bit: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YP17UR

Comment: Hopefully you know about [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) as well. Helps a lot to show someone's code to others in working/breaking state. Just so you're informed. :)

Comment: Your solution although plausible is not a good solution for two reasons: 1. it's slow due to reflection and 2. beats the purpose of generics. But it is a solution after all.

Comment: added another one with more interface usage. Still not pretty, but seems to be more clear than others: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ojGPqe