# Why we cannot call constructor of base class from derived

Tags: asp.net, oop, c#-4.0

I need to understand the concept that why we cannot call constructor of base class from derived. I have some scenario.

```
public class clsA
    {
        int i = 10;
        public void CallA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called by Class A");
        }
    }

    public class clsB : clsA
    {
        int i = 20;
        public void CallB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called by Class B");
        }

    }
```

if i do like that

```
clsA _obja = new clsA();
```

then constructor of base class called and we get its methods.

if i do like that

```
clsB _objb = new clsB();
```

then also constructor of base class called and we get base class methods and derived class methods as well.

if i do like that

```
clsA _objab = new clsB();
```

then constructor of base class called and we get its methods.

But now my question is that why we cannot call constructor of base class from derived class like

```
clsB _objb = new clsA();
```

Please suggest me. I want simple answer.

Comment: A lot of answers as to why a derived class reference cannot refer to a base class object: ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729527/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-base-class-object-to-a-derived-class-reference-with-a) though the wording is slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the constructor calls.  The problem is that you can't assign an instance of a parent class to a variable of a child class.  A `clsB` instance is a `clsA`, but a `clsA` object is not necessarily a `clsB`.