# AutoMapper DynamicMap not working

Tags: c#, automapper

I have created a generic method for mapping between List.
It was working fine up to AutoMapper Version 3.3.1.
After Version 4.0.0 its not working

```
public class Helper<T> : List<T> where T : new()
{
    public void MapBetween(List<T> NewList, List<T> OldList)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var NewItem in NewList)
            {
                string PrimaryKey = NewItem.GetType().GetProperties().First(f => f.Name.ToLower() == typeof(T).Name.ToLower() + "id").GetValue(NewItem).ToString();
                var OldItem = OldList.Find(delegate(T p) { return p.GetType().GetProperties()[0].GetValue(p).Equals(PrimaryKey); });
                AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap(NewItem, OldItem);//Mapping
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

public class Ac
{
    public string AcId { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public void ConvertList()
{
        List<Ac> OldList = new List<Ac>();
        OldList.Add(new Ac { AcId = "1", A = "Old A", B = "Old B" });

        List<Ac> NewList = new List<Ac>();
        NewList.Add(new Ac { AcId = "1", A = "new A", B = "new B" });

        Helper<Ac> helper = new Helper<Ac>();
        helper.MapBetween(NewList, OldList);
}
```

Is there is any changes required in my approach?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: value is not mapping newi tem to old item

Comment: @Avinash did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mapping to/from the same type, AutoMapper is using its `AssignableMapper` which simply assigns the value of the source object (an item in `NewList`) to the destination object (an item in `OldList`).  Since `Ac` is a reference type but passed by value, when source is set to destination, the result never makes it back out to your destination object.

AutoMapper uses `<SourceType>.IsAssignableFrom(<DestinationType>)` when determining if `AssignableMapper` should be used and because the types are the same it uses it.  (Potentially AutoMapper should check `IsValueType` as well when determining if it can be used).

Without more context, I'll take a stab at how to make this work to give you an idea.  You could define a new type (e.g. `AcNew`) that inherits from the existing (`Ac`) and then use it for either `NewList` or `OldList`.  For example, you could define a new type as:

```
public class AcNew : Ac {}
```

In `ConvertList()`, you would then use:

```
List<AcNew> NewList = new List<AcNew>();
NewList.Add(new AcNew { AcId = "1", A = "new A", B = "new B" });
```

When you do that, AutoMapper will no longer use `AssignableMapper` as assignment is [not possible between base & derived types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729527/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-base-class-object-to-a-derived-class-reference-with-a).

Regards,

Ross