# Initialise View Model that inherits from base model with values from base model

Tags: c#

I have a function that returns `Class1Model`

```
Class1Model model = GetClass1Model();
```

I also have a `Class1ViewModel` that inherits from `Class1Model` to which I have added some get only properties for formatting in a view.

```
public class Class1ViewModel : Class1Model  
{
    public string MyFormattedProperty => $"{base.Height:###.00} x {base.Width:###.00}" 
}
```

So I was hoping that I could do this:

```
Class1Model model = GetClass1Model();
var viewModel = model as Class1ViewModel;
```

But this doesn't work

So how would this usually be done?

Comment: Your object isn't a `Class1ViewModel`.  It's a `Class1Model`.  If you want a `Class1ViewModel`, you will need to return one from your method.

Comment: Composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: Sounds like cloning to me. Serialize base class, deserialize **as** inherited.

Comment: Composition ? Does that mean passing the model to the viewmodel via constructor and initialising a property of type model on the viewmodel?

Comment: And @Sinatr, how would cloning work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a composition approach instead of inheritance.

```
class Class1Model
{
    // model properties
}

class Class1ViewModel
{
    public Class1ViewModel(Class1Model model)
    {
        _Model = model;
    }

    private Class1Model _Model;
    public Class1Model Model { get { return _Model; } }

    // viewmodel specific extensions

    public string MyFormattedProperty => $"{Model.Height:###.00} x {Model.Width:###.00}"
}
```

If you expect your model properties to change, you should subscribe to model property changes with some weak event listener and issue appropriate property changed events for dependent viewmodel properties.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast an instance of the base type to the sub-type which is not allowed.

An Class1ViewModel is a Class1Model. Not the other way around.

So this would work:

```
Class1ViewModel viewModel = new Class1ViewModel();
Class1Model model = viewModel;
```

Comment: It's true you can cast to base types, but this doesn't solve the problem in question, where a model is given first.

Comment: The word "necessarily" isn't well chosen IMO. A base class is never one of its subclasses. There may be a conversion operator, but that's a distinct special case (and usually not considered a good use of a conversion operator).

Comment: well.. he needs to create a new instance of the sub type. I thought that was self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

In general it makes no sense (read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729532/1997232)), so I am not sure if providing *general* solution is a good idea.

You can do surely have one, e.g. via cloning via serialization trick:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Base
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
}

class Inherited : Base
{
    public string C = "c";
}

// in some method
var @base = new Base { A = "a", B = "b" };
var inherited = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Inherited>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@base));
```

`inherited` will have `@base` values (I used fields, should work for properties too) copied and own values will be default.

This is *very slow* approach. Consider to use manual copy instead:

```
var @base = new Base { A = "a", B = "b" };
var inherited = new Inherited { A = @base.A, B = @base.B, C = "whatever" };
```