# Is this a correct way of having a sub class override a super classe's member type ? And does it break SOLID principles and design patterns?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, subclass, solid-principles

**The question should be language agnostic, but in this case C# is used.**

There are 2 classes: `Context` and `Context<T>`.

`Context` contains `MainObject` which is of type `dynamic` (can be of type `object` as well)
`Context<T>` needs to specify more the `MainObject` type.

The main purpose is to be able to use the `Context` class in services and functions that doesn't have the responsibility of knowing the specific type of `MainObject` at compile time.

For example The `Serialize` method accepts `Context` as an argument while the `ResolveUiWidget` method accepts `Context<UiWidget>` as parameter. Also if `var context = Context<UiWidget>` Serialize(context)` is a valid statement. So this design seems beneficial.

**Is this a wrong approach or does it break the SOLID principles and design patterns ? If yes, is there another way of satisfying the parameters of `Serialize` and `ResolveUiWidget` methods ?

Maybe this is looking too much into the future but as a learning experience, getting a sense that Likov principle can be broken but not able to fully see a scenario.**

This is the current code:

```
    public class Context
    {
        public virtual dynamic? MainObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context<T>: Context
    {
        public new T? MainObject { get; set; }

        public Context()
        {
            MainObject = base.MainObject;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not flip it on its head and have `Context : Context<object>` instead of `Context<T> : Context`?

Comment: But the relationship has meaningfully changed. What if casting is needed ? `(Context) Context<T>` is not valid. Given `T` is any type

Comment: Hm, seems casting being even considered answers your question about Liskov taking a beating here ;-)

Comment: IMHO this is okay and I made something similar and absolutely matches.

Comment: @Oliver Thank you. Yes seems okay but Guru Stron asnwer's pointed out a bug that could totally happen with this design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest moving from classes to interfaces, ideally read-only (i.e. with no `set` property method).

Why read-only:

1. Currently your design has huge problem (even if you were able to compile it):

```cs
Context<int> x = ...;

public void AcceptsBaseContext(Context ctx)
{
    ctx.MainObject = "haha";
}

AcceptsBaseContext(x);
```

2. You can make interfaces [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) and implement non-generic [interface explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation), similar to what `IEnumerable` does:

```cs
public interface IContext
{
    object? MainObject { get; }
}

public interface IContext<out T> : IContext
{
    new T? MainObject { get; }
}

public class Context<T> : IContext<T>
{
    public T? MainObject { get; }
    object? IContext.MainObject => MainObject;

    public Context(T? obj)
    {
        MainObject = obj;
    }
}
```

Or you can change the generic interface to:

```cs
public interface IContext<T> : IContext
{
    new T? MainObject { get; set; }
}

public class Context<T> : IContext<T>
{
    public T? MainObject { get; set; }
    object? IContext.MainObject => MainObject;

    public Context(T? obj)
    {
        MainObject = obj;
    }
}
```

If you need to write to the property.

Either way method which are context type agnostic can work with it via `IContext` interface while you still preserve type safety.

Comment: Thank you. Seems a more reasonable approach. It should also solve the casting problem. But this is another post that shattered my previously read posts that teaches when to use interface vs abstract class : \ (Use interface for action intended methods). Any documentation or explanation that gives a somewhat general rule to when to use an interface vs abstract class ?

Comment: A paper that dives deep in details maybe ? Or covers multiple use cases ?

Comment: @EEAH interface is basically a contract, personally I think that working with abstraction over concrete implementation is preferable approach for medium to big projects cause it allows to decouple a lot of things and make code more unit testable and potentially more flexible. Abstract class allows you to share some implementation (which is also a point for debate - composition over inheritance is principle which gained quite big following) and it applicable in quite a lot of scenarios but in this particular it seems you care about contract cause there is not much to share in implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the generic version fits for your requirements:

```
public class Context<T>
{
    public T? MainObject { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use any type:

```
var test = new Context<dynamic>();
test.MainObject = "1";
```

or:

```
var test = new Context<string>();
test.MainObject = "1";
```

or:

```
var test = new Context<int>();
test.MainObject = 1;
```

### UPDATE:

> The Serialize method accepts Context as an argument while the
> ResolveUiWidget method accepts Context as parameter.

So we can inherit from `Context<T>`. And code would like this:

```
public class Context : Context<dynamic> 
{ }
```

And you can use `Context` class in `Serialize()` method.

It is true that [it is not possible to cast base class to derived](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729532).

However, we can write custom converter and use it:

```
public class ContextCast<T>
{
    public Context ToContext(Context<T> genericContext) 
    {
        return new Context() { MainObject = genericContext.MainObject};
    }
}
```

And your code would look like this:

```
Context<string> contextStr = new Context<string>() { MainObject = "Hello!"};

Context cntxt = new ContextCast<string>().ToContext(contextStr);
```

> Is this a wrong approach or does it break the SOLID principles and
> design patterns ? If yes, is there another way of satisfying the
> parameters of Serialize and ResolveUiWidget methods ?

In my view, it does not break SOLID principles as `MainObject` is just property which can be read or set. Behaviour of this object is always the same in base and derived classes.

Comment: Why you are using the `new` keyword on property in your example? I think you should remove it

Comment: @T.Dominik thanks! I’ve updated my answer! Please, see my updated answer!

Comment: Thank you. But this does not satisfy the Serialize method. `Serialize(Context)`. IT would become generic it self which is not desired

Comment: @EEAH please, see my updated asnwer